# C++ Struct to string

Tags: c++, string, structure

I'm currently making a game where either two people can play on one screen or one player can play vs the computer.

I currently have a simple structure made for my game:

```
struct game{
    string name;
} player1, player2;
```

I know you can use cout and cin to change the name like so:

```
cout << "What is Player 1's name?\n";
cin >> (cin,player1.name);
```

Is there a way to for example set `player1.name` to `"computer"` without using `cout`/`cin`?

Or maybe there is another way that I don't know of that doesn't use structures?

Comment: Something like `player1.name = "computer";`?  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to for example set `player1.name` to `"computer"` without
>   using `cout`/`cin`?

You mean....

```
player1.name = "computer";
```

---

Also

> `cin >> (cin,player1.name);`

I don't know what you are trying to do here. Just write

```
cin >> player1.name;
```

And since we are here

```
struct game{
    string name;
} player1, player2;
```

This is bad style. I mean declaring variables in the same expression as declaring the class.

First of you should not use global variables. Second, even when you do, declare them in a separate declaration.

Another thing to think about: is `player1` of type `game`? That doesn't sound right. Maybe name the class `Player` or `player_t`, depending on your style guide.

Comment: "even when you do" no, no, no, no, ... using global variables for such things causes dead kitties.

Comment: @J.Doe I mean even when you need to use global variable (not for this kind of things). Like it or not, sometimes you do need to use them albeit extremly rare.

Comment: "(not for this kind of things)" you should have added this tho your answer ;)